# Lightbox2 image formatter in view not adding click event

Tags: views, javascript

I have a view with an image field in it. I also have two different image styles, "timelinr" and "timelinr-modal". What I want is the thumbnail image to be the first style, and when its clicked on have it come up in a modal with the second style.

I have setup my settings on my image like the following,

[image]

For some reason though, this is not adding a click event to my image in the view. Am I doing something wrong here, or should I go about this a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a view and do settings as per the screenshot below.

   [image]
2. Choose Formatter as described below for **content:image**

[image]

Now you will have thumbnail image of the style **"timelinr"** and when clicked it will come up with image style **"timelinr-modal"**.

I tested above and it is working.